Screen State doesn't redraw when returning to the screen from a navigation stack
I'm writing a tool in Flutter to help generate a Json file and present the user with a form to fill out so that the JSON file can be generated.
The document has a few subsections which I try to create separate screens for the user to enter data.
On the first screen, there is a section which displays a list of "Pipelines" and has a button below it that says "Add pipeline". In the beginning when the list is empty nothing is displayed.
The user clicks Add Pipeline and then a new screen is pushed on the navigation stack where Pipeline specific inputs are provided by the user. The User then hits done and the the previous screen is popped from the navigation stack and displayed. My issue is that the screen is not redrawn with the new state. I'm expecting an entry to be added to the list.
I'm using riverpod for state management. I have a class call NewFileSession and create a provider which provides an instance of this to the app. This is the class
class NewFileSession implements Session {
  @override
  final String uuid = const Uuid().v4();
  TestSpecDocument? doc;
  final List<PipelineBuilder> pipelineBuilders = [];

  void reset() {
    doc = TestSpecDocument(
      matchList: [
        "Pipelines"
      ],
    );
    pipelineBuilders.clear();
  }

  bool get atLeastOneNamedPipeline => pipelineBuilders.any((element) {
    print("isTyped: ${element.isTyped}");
    return element.isTyped;
  });
  List<String> get pipelineNames => pipelineBuilders.map((e) => e.type.toString()).toList();
  bool get atMaximumPiplines => pipelineBuilders.length == 3;

  PipelineBuilder createPipeline() {
    pipelineBuilders.add(PipelineBuilder());
    print("Pipeline Count: ${pipelineBuilders.length}");
    return pipelineBuilders.last;
  }

  void submitPipelineBuilder(PipelineBuilder builder) {
    print("atLeastOneNamedPipeline Before: $atLeastOneNamedPipeline");
    pipelineBuilders.add(builder);
    print("atLeastOneNamedPipeline After: $atLeastOneNamedPipeline");

  }
}

In my first screen, in the build routine, I watch the property atLeastOneNamedPipeline which is a computed property. (I've also tried this watching the pipelines list as well). My Pipeline input screen, creates an instance of the Pipeline, fills it with some data and inserts in the NewFileSession instance by using the provider as well.
My expectation is that the first screen that is watching the property should detect the change and redraw, but this doesn't happen. The build method is never called again.
Here are the screens
This is the first Screen
class NewSessionWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NewSessionWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final session = ref.watch(newFileProvider);
    final atLeastOneNamedPipeline = ref.watch(
        newFileProvider.select((value) => value.atLeastOneNamedPipeline));
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      print("Going to Build");
      return Row(
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (atLeastOneNamedPipeline)
            PipelineList(list: session.pipelineNames),
          if (!session.atMaximumPiplines)
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              label: const Text("Add pipeline"),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                      body: Screen(PipelineEditor()),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

and this is the second screen called the PipelineEditor (there isn't much there now because I'm just trying to see things work)
class PipelineEditor extends ConsumerWidget {
  final PipelineBuilder _builder = PipelineBuilder();
  PipelineEditor({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        DropdownMenu<ModelTypeDisplay>(
          dropdownMenuEntries: [
            for (var v in ModelTypeDisplay.values)
              DropdownMenuEntry(
                value: v,
                label: v.label,
              ),
          ],
          onSelected: (value) {
            _builder.type = value?.type;
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          label: const Text("Add"),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.done),
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(newFileProvider).submitPipelineBuilder(_builder);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

What am I getting wrong with the provider. I'm modifying a list in the provided object in a sub-screen and am watching a property in the provided object in the parent list, but the parent UI does not redraw on the update.
Any advice would be appreciated
--- EDIT ---
This is my provider
@riverpod
class NewFile extends _$NewFile {
  @override
  NewFileSession build() {
    return NewFileSession(); 
  }

}


hey issue  might be related to how the state is managed with Riverpod am I right

Yes it is most likely related to that, though I'm not sure what. I'm a noob to Riverpod and flutter in general

Riverpod is designed to work with immutable data.
Since NewFileSession and PipelineBuilder are mutable, rivepod has no good way to compare between them.
In order for this to work, you need to rewrite your classes to be immutable and update them using copyWith methods.
freezed and dart_mappable can be very handy here.
If it is not possible for you to change you classes, then consider using a ChangeNotifierProvider instead of a regular riverpod class
